# Git submodule with same name in different branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

I was wondering whether it is possible to have a git submodule pointing to two different repositories *using the same directory name*, depending on the branch currently checked out.

```
overall-repo (Branch A)
\subproject at domainA

overall-repo (Branch B)
\subproject at domainB
```

If I try this using the regular `git submodule add` command, git wants me to specify a different name or force the previous target, although I have the other branch checked out.

Comment: It could work in theory: the `.gitmodules` file is source-controlled and hence can vary per commit, hence per branch; and the gitlink entry in a commit is also per-commit. In practice I think the existing submodule code just won't do it reliably, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else stumbles upon this, too: The name does not necessarily reflect the folder in which the submodule exists.

So the command 
`git submodule add --name subproject-B domainB subproject` 
creates the submodule with a unique name (`subproject-B`) but lets it reside in the path specified as last parameter.

Or, speaking in terms of the generated .submodule file:

```
[submodule "subproject-B"] #new name
    path = subproject #but same path
    url = domainB
```